# How to assign an array of int and strings into one string variable in swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, element

I have an array that takes in 2 types, a String and an Int the code looks like so

```
var totalDoubleSet1Array = [(Dante,10), (Cassius, 9), (Rio, 5)]
let sortedArray = totalDoubleSet1Array.sort { $0.1 > $1.1 }
```

I then use the sort function to arrange in order the highest score(Int) to the lowest with the name next to it. (So I can assign this to a string and display in an AlertAction)
I have seen it somewhere on here that yes I can print an Array of a single type of String or Int etc to the console but how can I Assign this array of 2 types (Stings and Ints) to a new Variable of String so I can assign it to a AlertAction message in swift please? Or even better how can I grab the individual element of each entry so I can assign it to a Var String? Hopefully this makes sense.. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an "array of two types", it's an array of *tuples*. You can grab an item from the array and take its individual parts like this:

```
let (name, score) = totalDoubleSet1Array[i]
```

After this assignment you would get two variables - `name` of type `String` that has the value of `i`-th element's name, and `score` of type `Int` that has the value of `i`-th element's score.

If all you need is the name, you have two options:

- You could use `let (name, _) = totalDoubleSet1Array[i]` syntax, or
- You could use `let name = totalDoubleSet1Array[i].1` instead.

Note that you are using the second syntax already in the comparison expression of your sorting function:

```
sort { $0.1 > $1.1 }
```

Comment: Thanks for this will try it and get back to you.. Im a rookie at this language and am learning and so thanks for the insight =) Awesome it works!

Answer (score 2):

According Apple tuples are not the best choice for data structures...

Why not just using a custom struct

```
struct Player {
    var name : String
    var score : Int
}

let totalDoubleSet1Array = [Player(name:"Dante", score:10), Player(name:"Cassius", score:9), Player(name:"Rio", score:5)]
let sortedArray = totalDoubleSet1Array.sort { $0.score > $1.score }
```

Then you can easily access the name for example in a table view

```
let player = sortedArray[indexPath.row]    
nameLabel.text = player.name
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I am learning this lang so will look into it. Appreciate the help.